# Ajax - what is faster: to change attribute or whole tag/content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i fetch some images with jQuery $get from one site and inject them in another.
I made two versions.
One time i have a div around the images and load the whole conent into
the site where i want them.

The other version has already image tags and i fetch just the src from every image tag on the other site and change them.

I wonder what is more efficient/faster:

```
// Get the images on current site
var coverFront = $(document.getElementById('cover-front'));
var coverBack = $(document.getElementById('cover-back'));

// Get the images src on other site via $.ajax get
var aCoverFront = $response.find('#cover-front').attr('src');
var aCoverBack = $response.find('#cover-back').attr('src');

// Change the images src on current site
coverFront.attr('src', aCoverFront);
coverBack.attr('src', aCoverBack);
```

v.s.:

```
// Get div on current site
var coverID = $(document.getElementById('cover'));

// Get the images inside the div on the other site via $.ajax get
var cover = $response.filter('#ajax-cover').html();

// Place images inside the div on current site
coverID.html(cover);
```

Sure, the div one has less operations. But the other one just needs to transfer the url.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, don't ask. **[Measure](http://jsperf.com).**

Comment: Try using firebug. It logs your request and the time it consumed.

Comment: In both versions there is only one request and no time difference. But somewhere here i was reading the advice to only transfer and change what you need in ajax.